# What is the meaning of the exterior derivative of a nonholonomic constraint?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, classical-mechanics

Suppose we have a nonholonomic mechanical system, say Lagrangian, for example the Chaplygin sleigh is a model of a knife in the plane. Its configuation space is $Q = S^1\times \mathbb{R}^2$ with local coordinates $q = (\theta,x,y)$. The nonholonomic constraint is "no admissible velocities are perpendicular to the blade" which is specified by a one-form

$$\omega_q = \sin\theta\,\mathrm dx + \cos\theta\,\mathrm dy.$$
When evaulating on a velocity $\dot{q}$ we specify the velocity constraint
$$v = \omega_q\cdot \dot{q} = -\dot{x}\sin\theta + \dot{y}\cos\theta = 0.$$

What is the mathematical/physical meaning of the exterior derivative of the constraint one-form? Since $\omega_q$ is a one-form, in physics, we typically interpret it as a force. Mathematically, we integrate this form over a 'line' to get the work due to the force over the 'line'. The exterior derivative is a 2-form, (does this have any physical significance??)

$$\mathrm d\omega = -\cos\theta\,\mathrm d\theta \wedge\,\mathrm dx - \sin\theta\,\mathrm d\theta \wedge\,\mathrm dy$$

If we evaluate this 2-form along a tangent (velocity) vector $\dot{q}$, we find the 'force'

$$\alpha_q = \mathrm d\omega(\dot{q},.) = \left(\dot{x}\cos\theta + \dot{y}\sin\theta \right)\,\mathrm d\theta - \cos\theta\dot{\theta}\,\mathrm dx - \sin\theta \dot{\theta}\,\mathrm dy.$$

Does this 'force', $\alpha_q \in T^*Q$, have any direct/obvious physical/mathematical physics/differential geometric  interpretation??

Thanks.

Comment: This is an interesting question (maybe better suited for physics SE). My first thoughts were as follows: Your form $\alpha_q$ is just $i_{\dot{q}} d \omega$. By the Cartan formula,
$$
i_{\dot{q}} d \omega = \mathcal{L}_{\dot{q}} \omega - d i_{\dot{q}} \omega
$$
But we've already said that
$$
i_{\dot{q}} \omega = 0
$$
Thus
$$
i_{\dot{q}} d\omega = \mathcal{L}_{\dot{q}} \omega
$$
Your form is precisely the Lie derivative of $\omega$ along $\dot{q}$. That is, it measures how $\omega$ changes as it is dragged along a curve satisfying the constraint.

Comment: But this doesn't work because $\dot{q}$ is not a vector field, so $d i_{\dot{q}} \omega$ doesn't make sense. We have to extend $\dot{q}$ to a vector field $X$ which also satisfies $\omega(X) = 0$ for the above analysis to go through. There must be a better way of looking at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, in a sense, the constraint one-form $\omega$ is not itself "physically meaningful": What matters the distribution $\mathcal{D}$ of "allowed directions", and there are many possible choices of (local) generating one-forms, and any interpretation of $d\omega$ will have to take this redundancy into account. Still there is a useful interpretation of $(d\omega)|_\mathcal{D}\neq 0$ as saying that the constraint $\omega(\dot{q})=0$ can be effectively circumvented by local motion.

Throughout, let $\mathcal{D}$ be a smooth distribution of constant rank on a manifold $M$, and $\Omega^kM$ denote the set of differential $k$-forms on $M$.

**1.An aside on the Frobenius theorem**

Given a differential form $\omega$. we may restrict it to $\mathcal{D}$ to obtain a smoothly varying alternating multilinear form $\omega|_\mathcal{D}$ on $\mathcal{D}$. The key property of one-forms that define the constraint is that they vanish when restricted in this way. Instead, we can define the set of *all* differential forms (of any order) which vanish when restricted to $\mathcal{D}$, denoted by $I_\mathcal{D}=\{\omega\in\Omega^kM:\omega|_\mathcal{D}=0\}$, which has a few useful properties.

- $I_\mathcal{D}$ is uniquely determined by the distribution $\mathcal{D}$.
- $I_\mathcal{D}$ is an ideal of of the algebra of differential forms, in the sense that for any $\omega\in I_\mathcal{D}$ and $\mu\in\Omega^kM$, we have $\omega\wedge\mu\in I_\mathcal{D}$.
- If defining one-forms $\omega_1,\cdots,\omega_m$ generate $\mathcal{D}$, then they also generate the ideal $I_\mathcal{D}$, in the sense that
  $$
  I_\mathcal{D}=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^m\omega_i\wedge\mu_i:\mu_1,\cdots,\mu_m\in\Omega^k M\right\}\cup\{0\}
  $$

A beautiful result known as the [Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(differential_topology)#Differential_forms_formulation) states that a distribution $\mathcal{D}$ is integrable (i.e. holonomic) if and only if the corresponding ideal is closed under exterior differentiation, i.e. $\omega|_\mathcal{D}=0\implies (d\omega)|_\mathcal{D}=0$. This implies we should look at the restriction $(d\omega)|_\mathcal{D}$ rather than $d\omega$ itself, and that this restriction should somehow indicate the extent to which the constraint imposed be $\omega$ fails to be integrable.

**2. "Violating" constraints with local motion**

Let $\omega\in I_\mathcal{D}$ be a constraint one form, and $X,Y\in\Gamma(D)$ be two vector fields compatible with the constraints. Starting at a point $p$ we can define a constraint-satisfying path with a time parameter $\tau$ and a speed parameter $v$:

- Flow along an integral curve of $vX$ for time $\tau$,
- flow along an integral curve of $vY$ for time $\tau$,
- flow along an integral curve of $-vX$ for time $\tau$,
- flow along an integral curve of $-vY$ for time $\tau$,
- repeat ad infinitum.

One can show that in the limit $\tau\to 0,v\to\infty$ with $v^2\tau=1$, this path approaches an integral curve of the Lie bracket vector field $[X,Y]$, so $[X,Y]$ is a kind of "average velocity" from alternately moving back and forth along $X$ and $Y$. We can then ask if this average velocity satisfies the constraint imposed by $\omega$:
$$\begin{align*}
\omega([X,Y])=&\omega([X,Y])+0-0 \\
=&\omega([X,Y])+X(\omega(Y))-Y(\omega(X)) \\
=&d\omega(X,Y)
\end{align*}$$
We see that it satisfies the constraint precisely when the vector fields satisfy $d\omega(X,Y)=0$. Conversely, if $(d\omega)|_\mathcal{D}\neq 0$ at $p$, we can find vector fields $X,Y$ which satisfy the constraints such that their alternating flow in the manner described above, starting at $p$, "violates" the constraint.

**3.Your example, and parallel parking**

If you're familiar with parallel parking, you have already seen this principle in action. Most automobiles are described more or less accurately by your model, in that they have a "heading" direction and can only move forward/backward along that direction or rotate their heading. However, by alternating small clockwise/counterclockwise rotations and forward/backward motion, they can *effectively* move perpendicular to their heading.

You can explicitly compute this: At the point $(x,y,\theta)=(0,0,0)$, the constraint $\omega_{(0,0,0)}=dy$ forbids motion in the $y$ direction. However, choosing vector fields $X(x,y,\theta)=\cos\theta\partial_x-\sin\theta\partial_y$ and $\Theta(x,y,\theta)=\partial_\theta$, we have $[X,\Theta]_{(0,0,0)}=\partial_y$ and $d\omega(X,\Theta)_{(0,0,0)}=1$, so alternately moving along these vector fields will result in effective motion in the $y$ direction.

Comment: Do constraints which you can/can't effectively violate through this sort of "wiggling" have names?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Constraints which cannot be violated this way are exactly integrable (i.e. holonomic) constraints. If if $\omega\neq0$ and $d\omega=0$ on a neighborhood, then you can find a local coordinate $y$ such that the constraint $\omega(\dot{q})=0$ is equivalent to $y(q)=\text{constant}$.